# Syntax error when use query in php

Tags: php, mysql

Anybody help me solve this query, error is syntax error,

> unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

```
 $sl = "select * from sanpham where id='$_GET['id']'";
```

Comment: Please dont use this code, Parameterize your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful with arrays and keys.

```
 $sl = "select * from sanpham where id='{$_GET['id']}'";
```

Or

```
 $sl = "select * from sanpham where id='" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
```

Comment: Careful with `$_GET` in SQL as well.

Comment: True ! if id can't be anything else than an integer, he should use : $sl = "select * from sanpham where id=" . intval($_GET['id']);

Comment: Preferred approach is `select * from sanpham where id = ?` then it wont matter what it is.

Comment: thank you, and this

Comment: $kq= mysqli_query($sl);
        if( mysqli_num_rows($kq) > 0){
            $d = mysql_fetch_array($kq);
        } and error are  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Comment: Yes.. Look at http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.query.php . mysqli_query need to be called with the link.